# Why there is a prefix like sDom, oLanguage in jQuery Datatable?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using a dataTable which I've initiated with,

```
var datatable = $('#datatble').DataTable({
    ... (Some stuff around there)
    oLanguage: {
        sSearch: '_INPUT_'
        lengthMenu: '_MENU_',
    },
    language: {},
    sDom: '',
});
```

My question is why there is a prefix for properties like `sDom, oLanguage, sSearch`?

Without `language: {},` the lengthMenu property did not work. Without the prefix, that corresponding property didn't work.

Please explain me, why is this happening?

What are those `prefix` are meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataTables has two naming standards:

- older Hungarian notation names (for versions prior to 1.10)
- newer camelCase names (from 1.10 onwards)

If you are using the latest version of DataTables (from version 1.10 onwards), you can use either the [new naming standard or the old one](https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-naming).

There is a page in the official documentation which [documents the mapping](https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-convert) between the two naming standards.

The new 1.10+ API is bigger than the old (pre-1.10) API, so there are some cases where there is no older Hungarian-style equivalent for the newer camelCase names.

Looking at one of the examples in your question:

```
oLanguage: {
  sSearch: '_INPUT_',
  lengthMenu: '_MENU_',
}
```

There is no such property as `oLanguage.lengthMenu` - it has to be:

- `sLengthMenu` if you are using `oLanguage` (old style)
- `lengthMenu` if you are using `language` (new style)

I would recommend using the new names wherever possible - especially on new projects. The Hungarian notation option **is deprecated and will be removed** in future versions. But you will see the old names used by a lot of older examples and tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

These specify the type of variables they are. `s` is string, `b` is Boolean, `o` is an object etc. It's called [Hungarian Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) and specified on the their [FAQ](https://legacy.datatables.net/faqs) page